# XTest: XTestFakeKeyEvent behaves differently based on single or multilayout

Tags: input, keyboard, x11

I have a small problem regarding `XTestFakeKeyEvent` I have written this example program to demonstrate the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Display * display;

    //Try to attach to the default X11 display.
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if(display == NULL) {
        printf("Error: Could not open display!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    KeyCode inject = 29; // Should be XKB_KEY_Y

    sleep(10);

    XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, inject, True, 0);
    XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, inject, False, 0);
    XFlush(display);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with: `gcc -o xkb_test xkb_test.c -lX11 -lXtst`

What this program does: It connects to the X11 server, waits 10 seconds and then injects the Keycode `29` on the keyboard, which corresponds to the `y` key on US Keyboards.

Now the problem: I have a German Keyboard Layout (in comparison to US the z and y is switched for example) and this program will inject a `y` or a `z` based on this condition:

A `z` is injected when I have configured multiple layouts in MATE (so I have this layout switching applet in the statusbar)
A `y` in injected when I have only a single layout configured in MATE

Why does this behave differently? How can I provoke a consistent behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XTestFakeKeyEvent` accepts a keycode. Keycodes correspond to physical keys, not to characters mapped to them. If you want to send a character, you need to figure out which key it is mapped to *in the current layout*.

In a modern system you are likely to use Xkb and with Xkb layouts are called groups. You can get the current group in `XkbStateRec` with `XkbGetState`, and then translate  valid keycodes one by one until you get the keysym you need.

Translating a keycode with Xkb can be a bit daunting and I don't know of a simple bullet proof method. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233743/775806) has a working routine, the only thing it lacks is the group (it uses `group = 0`, you need to replace it with `state.group` where `state` is what you get from `XkbGetState`).

Note the symbol that will ultimately be sent depends on current shift and caps lock states. If you need a particular character case, you have to modify the keyboard state before injecting your keycode.

Comment: i know that, thanks for the precise informations. In my case, a `z` is mapped to the physical key that corresponds to keycode `29`, but the character this virtual keypress will produce depends on the layout list in mate. If I only have the german layout enabled, it will generate a `y`, if I have more than german in the list, but german is active, it will generate a `z`

Comment: Xkb or probably your DE uses two different mechanisms for keyboard remapping depending on whether you have one or more layouts enabled. With one layout it substitutes keycodes while with many layouts it leaves keycodes alone and uses different keycode-to-keysym mappings. Or this is my current understanding. My outlined solution should work regardless.