# How to get key modified by shift or caps lock for current keyboard layout on linux

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

I'd like to create linux method that returns key modified by shift or caps lock for current keyboard layout. I was able to do that for win32, but I don't know how to do linux version:

```
internal uint8_t
platform_fplKeyToAscii(UINT key, bool shift, bool capsLock)
{
    BYTE keyStates[256] = {};
    if (shift)
    {
        keyStates[16] = 0x80;
    }
    if (capsLock)
    {
        keyStates[20] = 0x80;
    }

    wchar_t result[5];
    HKL keyboardLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(0);

    if (ToUnicodeEx(key, 0, keyStates, result, 4, 0, keyboardLayout))
    {
        return (uint8)result[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157826/xkb-how-to-convert-a-keycode-to-keysym